# JS hover menu appearing behind DIV on my website

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, z-index

I'm begging for your assistance.  The drop down menus on this web page I'm working on are appearing behind the #content div.  I'm certain it's a z-index issue, but I've combed through my CSS and can't find anything that would cause this.

**Page with the problem:** http://www.kent.edu/about/responsive/

**Working page for comparison:**  http://www.kent.edu/about/

Note: I know the script used for the menus is clunky, but I have to stick with it for now unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My advice, remove all z-index properties from your CSS and start adding them from scratch. `z-index: 9999` is not the best practice. Check for overflows as well.

Answer (score 1):

`#main_nav` has `overflow: hidden` applied to it, so `#main_nav` is not allowing your dropdowns to show

removing `overflow: hidden` from `#main_nav` should do the trick.